# Video play on hover of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to play a video when someone hovers on an image and if they click it a pop should display playing that video so far I have achieved pop up and displaying video `onclick` but I want to achieve this hover thing

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="resources/image.jpg"  data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fIHH5-HVS9o?autoplay=1" onclick="showVideo(this)"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="resources/image.jpg"  data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fIHH5-HVS9o?autoplay=1" onclick="showVideo(this)"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <   img src="resources/image.jpg"  data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fIHH5-HVS9o?autoplay=1" onclick="showVideo(this)"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function showVideo(obj){
    $("#youtube").attr("src", $(obj).data("src"));
    $("#videoModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function () { 
        $("#youtube").removeAttr("src");
    }).modal('show');
}
```

Some more HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="videoModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <iframe id="youtube" width="100%" height="500px">
</iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just want to comment , that what I think you actually want is for a slide show of clips from the video to start on hover then on click the video plays.  If that is correct players like jwplayer and other ones already handle that

Comment: NO its like 12 videos on my page but they all have images so if someone take move and moves over to that particular image the video should start instead of image and if they hover to other image the previous one should pause and if they click on it then video plays in popup

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery hover function and your own function to play the video:

```
$('#element').hover(function() {
    showVideo();
});
```

Comment: Does the .hover with just an alert work (read: does the hover not work, or is it the showvideo that doesnt work) maybe you use the wrong element?

Comment: alert works if I Catch the element #youtube but I am not able to figure out which element to catch can you please help me figuring that out?? I am trying to catch img tag   I assigned an id to img tag but then alert won't work

Comment: can you help me figure that out?!?

Comment: When the alert works, and the showvideo function works, it has to work.
If not there may be something with the timing. Then there is something worng with showVideo()

you can put the alert in the showVideo(); to double check this.